# Difference between await and manual Task handling

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I would like someone to clarify the difference between awaiting many Tasks and manually waiting for their completion in a collection.

I have an XML reader class that has to process several hundred files and while optimizing it I found an interesting difference. I created two functions, both of which calls my
`private async Task ParseModelsFromFile(ConcurrentDictionary<TSettings, TResults> datas, string filePath)` function. This basically loads all my models from the XML file on the given `filePath`. The only difference is in the calling and awaiting of this `ParseModelsFromFile()` function.

The first function: `ProcessFiles()` uses the `await` keyword, the second: `ProcessFilesWithTasks` creates a `Task` object for every single `filePath`, puts it in a collection of `Task`s and waits for all of them to complete.

**The second version with the Task collection is much faster. It takes about half the time.** I was thinking that these two functions will do the same thing and the only difference is going to be the use of the `async` keyword.

I did test this with several amounts of files and the function using await always comes out to be about 2x slower.

```
    private async Task ProcessFiles(ConcurrentDictionary<TSettings, TResults> datas, BlockingCollection<string> filePaths)
    {
        if (filePaths.Count == 0)
            return;

        foreach (var filePath in filePaths.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            await ParseModelsFromFile(datas, filePath);
        }
    }

    private Task ProcessFilesWithTasks(ConcurrentDictionary<TSettings, TResults> datas, BlockingCollection<string> filePaths)
    {
        if (filePaths.Count == 0)
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        List<Task> runningTasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var filePath in filePaths.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            runningTasks.Add(ParseModelsFromFile(datas, filePath));
        }

        Task allTasks = Task.WhenAll(runningTasks.ToArray());
        allTasks.Wait();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you understand how asynchronous code works, you'll understand why. So let's first look at what `ParseModelsFromFile` does. When it is called, it runs until the first `await` inside that method, which is probably where it reads the file. During the time that the OS and hardware goes out to read the file, there is nothing for your application to do. It is at this point that `ParseModelsFromFile` *returns*. It returns a `Task` that you can use to know when the rest of the method completes.

Knowing that, we can talk about the differences between your two implementations:

Using `await` means: don't do anything until this task completes. The thread is freed up to do other things, which is the benefit of asynchronous programming. But execution of your method stops until the task is complete. So using `await` inside the `foreach` loop will process one file and wait until it is completely processed before moving to the next iteration of the loop.

Whereas in `ProcessFilesWithTasks`, because you're not using `await` when you call `ParseModelsFromFile`, you are using that time that the OS is retrieving the file to move to the next iteration of the loop and start running `ParseModelsFromFile` for the next file.

If this is in an application where there is no synchronization context (like ASP.NET Core, console, or Windows service for example), then the continuation of each call to `ParseModelsFromFile` (everything after the first `await`) will run on a different thread, which will also make each file process faster.

The only change I would make is to make `ProcessFilesWithTasks` `async` and use `await` on `Task.WhenAll()` instead of `.Wait()`:

```
private async Task ProcessFilesWithTasks(ConcurrentDictionary<TSettings, TResults> datas, BlockingCollection<string> filePaths)
{
    if (filePaths.Count == 0)
        return Task.CompletedTask;

    List<Task> runningTasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var filePath in filePaths.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        runningTasks.Add(ParseModelsFromFile(datas, filePath));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(runningTasks);
}
```

`Wait()` will block the thread from doing anything else. It will just sit idle. Using `await` will free up the thread to do other things while it waits.

You also don't need to call `.ToArray()` since [`Task.WhenAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) accepts `IEnumerable<Task>`, which `List<Task>` is.

Microsoft has some really well-written articles on [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) that I think you would benefit from reading.